# Object "new_panel" not found ggplotly error

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to use ggplotly with the following session info:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-ubuntu14-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base  

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_3.6.0      ggplot2_2.2.0     mra_1.0           frb_3.12
```

I am able to use the plot_ly function like so with the correct graph being made, so the plotly package seems to be working:

```
ploty_ly(z = volcano, type = "surface")
```

But am having difficulty with the `ggplotly` function:

```
p<-ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = cyl)) +
geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y~x) +
geom_point()
```

The above creates the graph p which displays when called.

However, when I call `z <- ggplotly(p)`, I get the following error:

```
Error in get(x, envir = ns, inherits = FALSE) : 
object 'new_panel' not found
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error/how I can fix it?

Comment: You could try update `plotly` package to `plotly_4.5.6` . You could also try to restart your session. It works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Any idea what the "new_panel" error is caused by?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between ggplot2 v2.1 and v2.2, apparently the internal format was changed. Now ggplotly from plotly has to follow, which it does in its latest 4.x branch.

Therefore you should update to plotly4 which will work while plotly 3 doesn't.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: It worked! I just had to detach and re-attach ggplot2 and plotly after the update.